# Express.js - while loop before sending response

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

I'm trying to implement and existing solution in node.js, specifically, using express.js framework. Now, the existing solution works as follows:

- server exposes a GET service that clients can connect to
- when a client calls the GET service, the client number increments (a global variable) and then the number of clients is checked;
- if there are not at least 3 clients connected, the service is in endless loop, waiting for other clients to connect
- if (or rather, when) the rest of the two clients connect, the service sends respond to everyone that enough clients are connected (a 'true' value).

So what basically happens is, the client connects and the connection is active (in a loop) until enough clients connect, then and only then there is a response (to all clients at the same time).

Now I'm not expert in these architectures, but from what I think, this is not a correct or good solution. My initial thought was: this **must** be solved with sockets. However, since the existing solution works like that (it's not written in node.js), I tried to emulate such behaviour:

```
var number = (function(){
var count = 0;
  return {
    increase: function() {
        count++;
    },
    get: function(){
        return count;
    }
  };
})();

app.get('/test', function(req, res){
  number.increase();
  while (number.get() < 3) {
  //hold it here, until enough clients connect  
  }
  res.json(number.get());
});
```

Now while I *think* that this is not a correct solution, I have a couple of questions:

1. Is there any alternative to solving this issue, besides using sockets?
2. Why does this "logic" work in C#, but not in express.js? The code above hangs, no other request is processed.
3. I know node.js is single-threaded, but what if we have a more conventional service that responds immediately, and there are 20 requests all at the same time?

Comment: In node.js, you should be thinking "event-based".  The event-based solution to this problem would be to go to the code that accepts a new client connection and at the end of that code, check how many connections you have and then trigger whatever you need to trigger there.  You cannot "wait" with a `while()` look in node.js.  You simply can't do that.

Comment: could you provide an example for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably use an event emitter for this:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var emitter      = new EventEmitter();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // Increase the number
  number.increase();

  // Get the current value
  var current = number.get();

  // If it's less than 3, wait for the event emitter to trigger.
  if (current < 3) {
    return emitter.once('got3', function() {
      return res.json(number.get()); 
    });
  }

  // If it's exactly 3, emit the event so we wake up other listeners.
  if (current === 3) {
    emitter.emit('got3');
  }

  // Fall through.
  return res.json(current);
});
```

I would like to stress that @Plato is correct in stating that browsers may timeout when a response takes too much time to complete.

**EDIT**: as an aside, some explanation on the `return emitter.once(...)`.

The code above can be rewritten like so:

```
if (current < 3) {
  emitter.once('got3', function() {
    res.json(number.get());
  });
} else if (current === 3) {
  emitter.emit('got3');
  res.json(number.get());
} else {
  res.json(number.get());
}
```

But instead of using those `if/else` statements, I return from the request handler after creating the event listener. Since request handlers are asynchronous, their return value is discarded, so you can return anything (or nothing). As an alternative, I could also have used this:

```
if (current < 3) {
  emitter.once(...);
  return;
}
if (current === 3) {
...etc...
```

Also, even though you return from the request handler function, the event listener is still referencing the `res` variable, so the request handler scope is maintained by Node until `res.json()` in the event listener callback is called.

Comment: nice! this works as well and I think it's pretty close to what you might call _correct_. However, why is there a delay when the third client connects? It's like a 5 second (or more) delay before the values are returned. Any ideas?

Comment: @uglycode does your route handler look exactly the same as the one I posted, or is it doing other stuff that may be causing that 5-second delay? During a quick test with the code above the responses were instantaneous when the third client connected.

Comment: Ok will look into it, perhaps there's some legacy code...also, is there any prticular reason you 'return' res.json and emmiter.once?

Comment: @uglycode force of habit on the returns, although the one before `emitter.once()` _is_ required (otherwise it will fall through and call the `res.json()` line at the end of the handler).

Comment: Thanks, so the return actually makes the emmiter wait? Otherwise it wouldnt execute and it would continue to the bottom (commented as fall through).

Comment: @uglycode I added some more explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your http approach should work
2. You are blocking the event loop so node refuses to do any other work while it is in the while loop
3. You're really close, you just need to check every now and then instead of constantly. I do this below with `process.nextTick()` but `setTimeout()` would also work:

---

```
var number = (function(){
var count = 0;
  return {
    increase: function() {
        count++;
    },
    get: function(){
        return count;
    }
  };
})();

function waitFor3(callback){
  var n = number.get();
  if(n < 3){
    setImmediate(function(){
      waitFor3(callback)
    })
  } else {
    callback(n)
  }
}

function bump(){
  number.increase();
  console.log('waiting');
  waitFor3(function(){
    console.log('done');
  })
}

setInterval(bump, 2000);
/*
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
  number.increase();
  waitFor3(function(){
    res.json(number.get());
  })
});
*/
```

Comment: Be aware that the first two clients will quite possibly time out before the third arrives. Also you won't get any indication of this, so your counter will only count connection attempts, not actual present users. I think you can do 'long polling' by sending some little chunks of information every now and then to prevent the request timeout, but i've never implemented this.

Comment: Thanks for your time and response! However, when I copied your code, it still hangs. I added this piece of code in waitFor3 function: console.log('called! ' +number.get() ); and it's always 1. It behaves basically the same as before... any ideas?

Comment: I had to replace `process.nextTick` with `setImmediate`. Editing with my working test case.

Comment: so where does the "app.get" comes into play here? I worked up something, I'm not sure if it's absolutely perfect, but it.. kind of.. works: https://gist.github.com/javascrewpt/debb9188410f394eed23

Comment: app.get is executed once per incoming request. If you make three requests in three separate tabs you should see them load.

Comment: OK thanks, just one question: is it OK to handle requests like that? Or are sockets more appropriate?

Comment: If you need accurate, real time presence information, use sockets. If you don't need socket features, this 'long request' option is a fine, simple option. But keep my earlier comment in mind that you don't actually know if the browser is still there on the other end of the request. And if you want to send realtime messages between browsers, sockets are going to make that job much easier.